# I don't see CommandController Command in TYPO3 scheduler

Tags: composer-php, typo3

I use TYPO3 8.10 I create an extension where I use scheduler. In ext_localconf.php I wrote

$GLOBALS['TYPO3_CONF_VARS']['SC_OPTIONS']['extbase']['commandControllers'][] = 'MyVendor\MeExt\Command\ImportCommandController';

If system build without composer I see the "CommandController Command" in scheduler. If system build with composer I don't see needed command.

In composer.json I wrote

```
"autoload" : {
  "psr-4" : {
    "MyVendor\\MyExt\\" : "path/typo3conf/ext/my_ext/Classes"
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried emptying caches and rebuilding autoload information using the Install Tool? Have you called 'composer dumpautoload'?

Comment: The issue is resolved. Need to run command "composer dump-autoload -a"

Answer (score 1):

After I did

```
composer dump-autoload -a
```

all classes became visible.